# Symfony2: Access Request object in Entity

Tags: symfony, request, locale

I'd like to know how to access the Request object in an entity (Symfony2) to modify the user locale.

If someone has found a solution for my problem, please let me know.

Comment: What have you tried yet? For what purpose do you need to access the Request object in an entity?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. This is by design: the entity is just a simple object that should know nothing about the request - it's the responsibility of the controller to interpret the request, and manipulate the entity based on that.

Something like:

```
//inside your controller:
public function fooBarAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = // get entity
    $entity->setLocale($request->getSession()->getLocale());
}
```

The above is just example code, it won't work if you just copy and paste it. It's just to demonstrate the general idea. The entity should just be a very simple object, who's only responsibility is to hold some data. It shouldn't know where the data is coming from - that keeps it flexible (if you want to set the locale based on something else, you only have to change your controller, not all your entities).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but...

What you can but **never** should do is inject the Request object into the entity (Practically turning your entity into service, see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)). Also, even **worse** idea (but which people still do), you could inject the whole container and get Request from there. The reason why you shouldn't do it is you never should have any code that deals with business rules or any system code in your entities.

You can switch your locale directly in your routes by using _locale custom variable (accessible also from the Request). Or you can create a [kernel listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html), which will do the required functionality for you. This way you keep your code testable and decoupled.